# Opengl will not display anything

Tags: c++, opengl, graphics

I'm trying to get a small triangle to display.

Here is my initialization code:

```
void PlayerInit(Player P1)
{
    glewExperimental = GL_TRUE; 
    glewInit();

    //initialize buffers needed to draw the player
    GLuint vao;
    GLuint buffer;
    glGenVertexArrays(1, &vao);
    glGenBuffers(1, &buffer);

    //bind the buffer and vertex objects
    glBindVertexArray(vao);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, buffer);

    //Set up a buffer to hold 6 floats for position, and 9 floats for color
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(float)*18, NULL, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    //push the vertices of the player into the buffer
    glBufferSubData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0, sizeof(float)*9, CalcPlayerPoints(P1.GetPosition()));

    //push the color of each player vertex into the buffer
    glBufferSubData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(float)*9, sizeof(float)*9, CalcPlayerColor(1)); 

    //create and compile the vertex/fragment shader objects
    GLuint vs = create_shader("vshader.glsl" ,GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
    GLuint fs = create_shader("fshader.glsl" ,GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);

    //create a program object and link the shaders
    GLuint program = glCreateProgram();
    glAttachShader(program, vs);
    glAttachShader(program, fs);

    glLinkProgram(program);

    //error checking for linking
    GLint linked;
    glGetProgramiv(program, GL_LINK_STATUS, &linked);
    if(!linked)
    {
        std::cerr<< "Shader program failed to link" <<std::endl;
        GLint logSize;
        glGetProgramiv(program, GL_INFO_LOG_LENGTH, &logSize);
        char* logMsg = new char[logSize];
        glGetProgramInfoLog(program, logSize, NULL, logMsg);
        std::cerr<< logMsg << std::endl;
        delete [] logMsg;
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    glUseProgram(program);

    //create attributes for color and position to pass to shaders
    //enable each attribute
    GLuint Pos = glGetAttribLocation( program, "vPosition");
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(Pos);

    GLuint Col = glGetAttribLocation( program, "vColor");
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(Col);

    //set a pointer at the proper offset into the buffer for each attribute
    glVertexAttribPointer(Pos, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, (const GLvoid*) (sizeof(float)*0));
    glVertexAttribPointer(Col, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, (const GLvoid*) (sizeof(float)*9));
}
```

I don't have much experience writing shader linkers, so I think that is where the problem might be.  I have some error checking in the shader loader, and nothing comes up. So I think that is fine.

Next I have my display and main function:

```
//display function for the game
void GameDisplay( void )
{
    //set the background color
    glClearColor(1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0);

    //clear the screen
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    //Draw the Player
    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3);
    glutSwapBuffers();
}

//main function
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_RGBA | GLUT_DOUBLE);
    glutInitWindowSize(500, 500);
    glutCreateWindow("Asteroids");

    Player P1 = Player(0.0, 0.0);
    PlayerInit(P1);
    glutDisplayFunc(GameDisplay);

    glutMainLoop();
    return 0;
}
```

Vertex shader :

```
attribute vec3 vPosition;
attribute vec3 vColor;
varying vec4 color;

void main()
{   
    color = vec4(vColor, 1.0);
    gl_Position = vec4(vPosition, 1.0);
}
```

Fragment shader

```
varying vec4 color;

void main()
{
    gl_FragColor = color;
}
```

That's all of the relevant code.  CalcPlayerPoints just returns a float array of size 9 to hold the triangle coordinates.  CalcPlayerColor does something similar.

One last problem that may help with diagnosing the problem is that whenever I try to exit the program by closing the window of the application, I get a breakpoint in the glutmainloop, however if I close the console window, it exits fine.

Edit: I added the shaders for reference.
Edit: I am using opengl version 3.1

Comment: Where are your shaders?  Those are kinda important :)

Comment: What GLSL version are you using? I don't see any #version directive.

Comment: Are you sure that your `Pos` and `Col` actually contains valid locations? I'm not convinced that the old `attribute` type will work here. Specifying your GL and GLSL version IS again very important!

Answer (score 2):

Without the shaders, we can't say if the faulty code isn't GLSL (bad vertices transformations, etc.)
Have you tried checking `glGetError` to see if the problem doesn't come from your initialization code ?

Maybe try to set the output of your fragment shader to, say, `vec4(1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0)` to check if its normal output is ill-formed.

Your last problem seems to unveil an undefined behavior, like bad memory allocation/deallocation, which may take place in your `Player` class (by the way consider passing the object as a reference in your initialization code, because it may at the moment trigger a shallow copy and then a double-free of some pointer).

Comment: Thanks for the response rems4e.  I added the shaders to the question.  I just tried calling the glGetError at the end of the init code.  It returns a 0, signifying that there is no error.  The code runs and compiles fine, it just doesn't display.  I have also edited the fragment shader to a vec4 of a solid color.  There was no difference.  Lastly, I changed the init code to take a pointer to the Player instead of a copy.  There was no change, but I will keep the change as it seems to be better practice.  Thank you for the suggestions.

Comment: Your shaders look right. But the fact that glGetError() returns 0 doesn't mean an error didn't happen in your code ! Its return value is reset to 0 after each GL call, and you have to check the value after each call to be sure non of them has comprised the GL state.

Comment: Ok, I will do that.  Thank you for the clarification.  I will comment back with the results.

Comment: Sorry for the extreme delay.  I have added glGetError after each of my gl calls in all of my code, and printed each one.  They all return 0.  So the gl state seems to be fine.  Do you have any other thoughts as to what might be causing the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out there was something wrong with how I was returning the array of vertices from the function used to compute them.  The rest of the code worked fine after that fix.